# How do I ensure that all network calls have been made before accessing my core data model?

Tags: ios, swift

I am making multiple api calls in succession and when I finally push to my next view controller my data comes up completely blank from my core data model. In `ViewController A` I have made the following requests in this order:

```
Api.verifyOtp(email, otp).continueWith { (task) -> Any? in
            if task.succeed {

                self.apiCallOne()
                self.apiCallTwo()
                self.apiCallThree()
                self.apiCallFour()
                self.apiCallFive()

            } else {
                Hud.hide()
                task.showError()
            }
            return nil
        }
```

Now all of these calls are made asynchronously. However the last method which is `self.apiCallFive()` is the method that pushes to `ViewController B`. Here is the call:

```
Api.apiCallFive().continueOnSuccessWith { (task) -> Any? in
        Hud.hide()
        if task.succeed {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let viewB storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB"                        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewB, animated: true)
        }
```

My guess is that since all of these requests are happening asynchronously then there's no guarantee on which call will finish first. So the `apiCallFive()` is pushing and loading ViewController B before the others are able to finish. How can I make it so the next view will not be loaded or pushed to until all of the tasks have been completed?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess those api calls also do something like writing the api call results to core data?

Comment: Yes, those are baked into the api requests. Once the call has finished retrieving the data an object is created and stored into core data.

Comment: do you get notified when other api call completed?

Comment: Whatever the solution, make sure you don't just freeze forever if any of the calls fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. Fix it by using `DispatchGroup`.

**Code:**

Define as `property`

```
let APIGroup = DispatchGroup()
```

Execute below code when any API Calling starts.

```
APIGroup.enter()
```

Execute below code when any API Calling Completed.

```
downloadGroup.leave()
```

Notify Block:

```
APIGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
    print("All APIs called successfully: Perform required operation")
}
```

There no need to manage by any counter or other variables. `notify` block call automatically when all task completed successfully.

> What’s really important here is the enter-leave pairs. You have to be
>   very careful and make sure that you leave the group. It would be easy
>   to introduce a bug in the code above. Let’s say that we didn’t leave
>   the group in that guard statement above, just before the return. If
>   the API called failed, or the JSON was malformed, the number of groups> entries would not match the number of leaves. So the group completion
>   handler would never get called. If you’re calling this method from the
>   UI and displaying an activity indicator while your networking requests
>   are running, you would never get a callback from the method, and you
>   would keep on spinning

[Apple documents](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup)

Comment: Mother of God this is a beautiful solution. So I take it that it would be best if operation failed I could either display a message notifying the user that they should check their network or any other error message and try again later? Also, stop the spinner from spinning ;)

Comment: @butter_baby Glad to hear. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

To solve this you need a way of getting notified when each call is finished.
The easiest way of doing this is using completion blocks on each call.

```
func apiCall(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    ....
}
```

After adding completion blocks to the api calls, your blocks could look like this:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

dispatchGroup.enter()
apiCallOne {
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}

dispatchGroup.enter()
apiCallTwo {
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}

...


dispatchGroup.enter()
apiCallN {
    dispatchGroup.leave()
}
dispatchGroup.wait(timeout: Constants.timeout)
```

Keep in mind that the `wait` statement will block the thread where you call it until all the `leave()` statements are executed, so be careful that you don't end up with a deadlock.

Comment: Ah, excellent. I am actually calling most of these from a single Api class and it would not be a good idea to enter the dispatch group inside these methods since they're used elsewhere in my project as well. So it's safe to call `dispatchGroup.enter()` outside of the method like that and then just `dispatchGroup.leave()` inside of the completion handler?

Comment: Yep calling them like I showed above should be ok. Not sure if I completely understood your question though.